# Search facility like CONTAINS or FREETEXT using Linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I'm hoping that the title of this is pretty straight forward enough.  Basically, I have a database which doesn't have the Full-text indexing installed.  Rather than installing the Full-text indexing, I was wondering if there is a way of doing this with Linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write LINQ queries that use instance methods on `System.String`. Most LINQ providers are able to convert this to SQL statements. For instance:

```
from customer in db.Customers
where customer.Name.Contains("foo") || customer.Name.Contains("bar")
select customer;
```

LINQ to Entities will convert this to something like this:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Customers T1
WHERE T1.Name LIKE '%' + @p1 + '%'
OR T1.Name LIKE '%' + @p2 + '%'
```

Note that when you need a dynamic number of words to search for, you can use the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). It allows you to build predicates that contain OR statements. Rewriting it with unions is also an effective method. For instance:

```
string[] searchWords;

// Define an empty set.
var customers =
    from customer in db.Customers
    where false
    select customer;

// Union the empty set with a set for a word.
foreach (var temp in searchWords)
{
    var searchWord = temp;

    customers = customers.Union(
        from customer in db.Customer
        where customer.Name.Contains(searchWord)
        select customer);
}
```

Comment: This can work with multiple words, but when you need a dynamic number of words, you need to write the LINQ query differently (with unions for instance) or use the PredicateBuilder: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that I don't know how many keywords are coming through.  So, if I have 3 keywords, then that will miss one out.

Comment: yep  -i love the predicatebuilder, definately a more elegant solution

Comment: ardman - with the predicate builder, you can simply loop round and build the expression based on the number of words that are in play (these expressions can be a variety of AND/OR/NOT etc)

Comment: Also look at the method of using the LINQ `Union` operator. See my updated answer.

Comment: lol : Steven keeps changing his answer each time I reply with comment. ;o)  I like the look of the Predicate Builder.

Comment: yes, stephen the 'fingers' :) +1 for an **ever evolving** answer :)

Comment: @Ardman: I work in an Agile manner; small steps at a time ;-)

Comment: @Steven:  I've marked as answer as I've decided to use PredicateBuilder.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are after something like:

```
from xx in table
where uids.Contains( xx.uid.ToString() )
select xx
```

?

If you are after seperate string searching, perhaps:

```
string input = "some String";
string[] toSearchFor = GetSearchStrings();
var containsAll = toSearchFor.All(x => input.Contains(x));
```

Comment: +1 - beat me to it re .All() ... that said, i feel that this general solution (trying to emulate freetext search) will be a real resource and performance hog for the OP.

Comment: I don't think that LINQ to Entities is able to handle the `All` operator.